# Leer fichero JSON Java

Tags: java, json

Tengo un fichero JSON el cual contiene información tipo clave-valor. Dicha información consta de caracteres que están almacenados en matrices de 8x8. A la hora de leerlo me devuelve todo el contenido del fichero y lo que quiero hacer es que me saque el valor de cada línea de la matriz.

```
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","3":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","4":"O 1 1 O O 1 1 O","5":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","6":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","7":"O O O O O O O O","8":"O O O O O O O O","time":"0.2"}
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","3":"O 1 1 O O 1 1 O","4":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","5":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","6":"O O O O O O O O","7":"O O O O O O O O","8":"O O O O O O O O","time":"0.2"}
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","3":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","4":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","5":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","6":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","7":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","8":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","time":"0.2"}
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","3":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","4":"O 1 1 O O 1 1 O","5":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","6":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","7":"O O O O O O O O","8":"O O O O O O O O","time":"0.2"}
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 1 O O 1 1 1","3":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","4":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","5":"O O O O O O O O","6":"O O O O O O O O","7":"O O O O O O O O","8":"O O O O O O O O","time":"0.2"}
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","3":"O 1 1 O O 1 1 O","4":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","5":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","6":"O O O O O O O O","7":"O O O O O O O O","8":"O O O O O O O O","time":"0.2"}
{"1":"1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1","2":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","3":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","4":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","5":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","6":"1 1 O O O O 1 1","7":"O 1 1 1 1 1 1 O","8":"O O 1 1 1 1 O O","time":"0.2"}
```

Ese es el contenido del fichero y lo que me muestra por consola y lo que quiero que me muestre es solo los 1 y los O.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            try {

                Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("pruebame.json"));

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


                // loop array
                JSONArray tag = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Tags");
                Iterator iterator = tag.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

Me gustaría conseguir que la salida por consola sea de la siguiente manera:

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 O O O O 1 1
1 1 O O O O 1 1
O 1 1 O O 1 1 O
O O 1 1 1 1 O O
O O 1 1 1 1 O O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSON

Hay un pequeño problema con la estructura del `JSON`, en el ejemplo que as dado, defines 7 Objectos independientes, con 9 "llaves" (1-8 + "time") y cada una de la "llave" contiene una cadena de caracteres.

Para tener una definición correcta del documento `JSON`, debería ser así:

```
[
    {
        "1":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        "2":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        ...,
        "8": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        "time":"0.2"
    },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... }        
]
```

Con esta estructura, defines una lista de objetos, el cual cada uno contiene 9 elementos "llave:valor" (1-8 y "time"), y las llaves 1-8 contienen listas de 8 elementos con valores numéricos.

Como propuesta, para mejorar la estructura de datos, te recomiendo una estructura como la siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "data":[
                [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
        ],
        "time": 0.2
    },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... }
]
```

Así te resultará más fácil analizar la estructura para extraer los datos.

Recomiendo esta página web para entender mejor la estructura del formato JSON: http://www.json.org/

### Java

Para extraer los datos, deberás iterar en la raíz de la estructura, para extraer cada uno de los objetos (Con el uso del Objeto en Java `JSONArray`), dentro de cada objeto del iterador, deberás extraer el objeto `data` que contiene una lista de 2 dimensiones e iterar las 2 dimensiones hasta extraer el valor deseado y con el objeto `time` extraerás los datos correspondientes.

Para hacer más fácil su comprensión, declaro la estructura `JSON` con el objeto en Java que representa cada elemento.

```java
[ -> JSONArray (raíz del objeto JSON)
    { -> JSONObject (primer valor de la lista de objetos de la raíz)
        "data":[ -> JSONArray (lista bidimensional, de la propiedad "data") 
                [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1], -> JSONArray (lista con los valores Integer ha analizar)
                [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
        ],
        "time": 0.2 -> Float | Double (valor de la propiedad "time")
    },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... }
]
```

Como recomendación final, el uso del framework Gson de google (si no es que ya lo usas): https://github.com/google/gson , el cual biene con documentación muy bien explicada

### Extra:

Si todo esto ya lo sabías y únicamente te preguntabas como iterar en la cadena de valores ->
"1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1", el uso del objeto `StringTokenizer` es tu mejor opción!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!